# How to solve matrix transformation of a vector?

Tags: vector-spaces

Given two non-zero vectors $a=(a_1, a_2)$ and $b=(b_1, b_2)$ we define $\sim(a,b)$ by $\sim(a,b)=a_1b_2-a_2b_1$. Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be points with position vectors $a$, $b$ and $c$ respectively, none of which are parallel. Let $P$ ,$Q$ and $R$ be points with position vectors $p$, $q$ and $r$ respectively, none of which are parallel.

**(i)** Show that there exist $2\times2$ matrix $M$ such that $P$ and $Q$ are the images of $A$ and $B$ under transformation represented by $M$.

Comment: I don't understand what the question have to do with the definition of $ \sim(a,b)$.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @EmilioNovati I expect that this comes into play in part (ii), (iii) or whatever of this homework exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$M =\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix}$$

$MA = B$ and $MB = Q$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} p_1 & q_1 \\ p_2 & q_2 \end{bmatrix} $$

A solution exists if $\begin{bmatrix} a_1 & b_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 \end{bmatrix}$ is invertible, by right-multiplying the above matrix equation by the inverse of this matrix. We are given that the vectors A and B are not parallel so that yes, the matrix is invertible and there is a unique solution for M.

The matrix is invertible iff its determinant is non-zero $\iff$  the defined function $\sim(a,b) \neq 0 \iff $ A and B are not parallel.